# How do I delete a collection in Django Rest Api?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've been trying for a while now to get 'DELETE' to work when reading a collection in Django Api View. I've been using 'ListCreateAPIView' and that only provides get and post method handlers. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**My view:**

```
class NotepadDetail(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Session
    serializer_class = SessionSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user=self.request.user
        notepad = self.kwargs['notepad_pk']
        return Session.objects.filter(user=user, notepad=notepad)

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.notepad = get_object_or_404(Notepad, user=self.request.user, pk=self.kwargs['notepad_pk'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by adding:

```
def get_object(self, notepad_pk):
    try:
        return Notepad.objects.get(user=self.request.user, pk=notepad_pk)
    except Notepad.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

def delete(self, request, notepad_pk, format=None):
    object = self.get_object(notepad_pk)
    object.delete()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `DestroyModelMixin`:

```
class NotepadDetail(generics.DestroyModelMixin,
                    generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Session
    serializer_class = SessionSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user=self.request.user
        notepad = self.kwargs['notepad_pk']
        return Session.objects.filter(user=user, notepad=notepad)

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.notepad = get_object_or_404(Notepad, user=self.request.user, pk=self.kwargs['notepad_pk'])

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The `self.destroy` method provided by the `DestroyModelMixin` will handle the object deletion, will correctly raise the `pre_delete` and `post_delete` signals, and will return the `204 NO CONTENT` status.

Comment: That just erased all the content in the collection, the collectionobject still exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
           event = self.get_object(pk)
           event.delete()
           return Response("Object Deleted")
```

Comment: You can define a function delete: get the particular object by using self.get_object(pk), here you get the primary key (pk) of that class using self(object of the same class). Then Just delete that object using delete().

Comment: Not to me. Add this to the post itself.